# Php versions (5.2.6 and 5.2.17) and joomla site

Tags: php, joomla1.5

We have a live environment with php 5.2.6 and IIS 6.0 and a development environment with php 5.2.17 and IIS 7.0. We will develop a new site with joomla 1.5.

We would like to know if we will have any compatibilities issues, if we first develop the site in php 5.2.17 and then we transfer it into live environment which has php 5.2.6

How can be sure that the site will work in the two environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to be sure the site will work in both environments is to test fully in both environments.  Ideally your development environment should mirror your live environment, or you should do proper testing in an environment that does mirror the live.  That should give you a reasonable level of certainty.

Joomla itself is very supporting of the various PHP foibles I've seen ... so as long as you meet the requirements for your release, I doubt you'll see any problems with the core code.  I can't speak for any you develop yourselves, or any plugins you use however.  Best to develop against a mirror of the live version.

Comment: The core code shouldn't have any issues running in either environment, though it does tend to be easier to set up properly in a LAMP environment.